# Extend JSON response with new property in REST API without breaking clients?

Tags: json, rest

If have a REST API with a GET end point, say /api/v1/unit/{id}, which returns a JSON describing the unit and looks something like:

```
{
   "id":123,
   "a":123
}
```

Can I extend the returned JSON with a new property and be safe that this will not cause trouble for the current consumers of the end point?
The new JSON will be like:

```
{
   "id" : 123,
   "a" : 123,
   "b" : 123
}
```

Or is this bad practice and I should make a new end point which returns the "new version" of the json? E.g: /api/v2/unit/{id}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is your need?

Comment: The question is if it is generally safe to extend a JSON with new properties or if this may cause trouble for the current consumers of the end pont. The current consumers does not know about the new "b" property that will be introduced.

Comment: If you change the API, there will be no issue in the existing script, since they would called the variable from JSON like result["id"] or result["a"] where result is the variable name of JSON. You can update the API.. Please make sure existing properties like id and a are coming in new API call as well.

Comment: you should be totally fine extending the current schema with a new property. this is not a breaking change

Answer (score 0):

First - about breaking the clients. It depends on your clients. For instance, if your Json is consumed by Java code there is a way to ensure that an unknown new property may be ignored. So, you need to check if your clients can handle this and if it is a default behavior or do you need to modify clients to be able to handle this. But in general it is possible to to extend your JSON and have old clients work. However, your new property is useless - at least for old clients. While this is possible, making a new end-point seems to be a cleaner solution

Comment: I thought some kind best practice existed for this case. I know that the new property is useless for old clients, since they don't know about it (yet) and they only care about "id" and "a". But new clients are also interested in "b", that's why I wanted to append the existing json with a new property instead of making a whole new end point.

Comment: It really depends on your config and application. Both approaches are valid. You just need to know pros and cons and choose the one that fits you the best